# Recurring contributions on paypal pro - undefined index

Tags: recurring-contributions

We have a contribution page with the option to mark the donation as recurring with the ability to specify the term (how many months). This was working well, until recently, we are receiving a big red notice at the top of the page, even though the contribution appears to have registered correctly with CiviCRM as well as with Paypal. Here's the error:

Notice: Undefined index: installments in CRM_Core_Payment_PayPalImpl->doDirectPayment() (line 371 of /[PATH_TO_CIVI]/crm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalImpl.php).

Any ideas as to what I need to do to make this error/notice go away?

EDIT: I checked line 371 in the file specified and this is the line:

```
 $args['totalbillingcycles'] = $params['installments'];
```

Which exists in the middle of the following If statement starting on line 356:

```
if (CRM_Utils_Array::value('is_recur', $params) == 1) {
      $start_time = strtotime(date('m/d/Y'));
      $start_date = date('Y-m-d\T00:00:00\Z', $start_time);

      $args['PaymentAction'] = 'Sale';
      $args['billingperiod'] = ucwords($params['frequency_unit']);
      $args['billingfrequency'] = $params['frequency_interval'];
      $args['method'] = "CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile";
      $args['profilestartdate'] = $start_date;
      $args['desc'] = "" .
        $params['description'] . ": " .
        $params['amount'] . " Per " .
        $params['frequency_interval'] . " " .
        $params['frequency_unit'];
      $args['amt'] = $params['amount'];
      $args['totalbillingcycles'] = $params['installments'];
      $args['version'] = 56.0;
      $args['PROFILEREFERENCE'] = "" .
        "i=" . $params['invoiceID'] . "&m=" . $component .
        "&c=" . $params['contactID'] . "&r=" . $params['contributionRecurID'] .
        "&b=" . $params['contributionID'] . "&p=" . $params['contributionPageID'];
    }
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you aren't using the most recent version of CiviCRM (4.7.27). In the current version of this file, that line has been replaced with:

```
$args['totalbillingcycles'] = CRM_Utils_Array::value('installments', $params);
```

The CRM_Utils_Array function is meant to prevent missing indices or variables that aren't even arrays from throwing warnings. (https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-13288).

I have no idea when the change in the code happened (what version/date).

I suggest you upgrade your CiviCRM. It looks like it would be relatively harmless to update the code manually, in this case.